# Send jQuery Selector to Callback Function

Tags: jquery, callback, selector, jquery-callback

How can I send the jQuery selector to a callback function? For example, the following code, on a button click, would hide the button selected by the jQuery object.

```
function cb (target) {
    target.hide();
}

$('#button').on('click', cb);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is executed within the scope of the element that raised the event so you don't need to pass anything - just use the `this` keyword. Eg. `$(this).hide()`:

```js
function cb() {
  $(this).hide();
}

$('#button').on('click', cb);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Hide me!</button>
```

Comment: Now, jshint is highlighting "this" and throwing an error: "Possible strict violation." If this is valid JavaScript, why the error?

Comment: Possibly because it thinks the function is not defined in the correct scope, hence `this` would not be the expected value. I can assure you this is entirely valid code. If you want to avoid the warning, put the function directly in the event handler: `$('#button').on('click', function() { $(this).hide() });`. Obviously this may prevent any DRY logic you were using though.

Comment: I found a better solution to suppress the jshint error, adding /* jshint validthis: true */ in the callback function since this is obviously valid code. Thanks for your help about using "this"!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it fixed!